# Retrieve the tzname from datetime.time

Tags: python

I am trying to check the tzname of datetime.time as

```
In [93]: t = datetime.time(6, 15, 30, 999999, dateutil.tz.gettz("UTC"))                                                       
In [94]: t                                                                                                                    
Out[94]: datetime.time(6, 15, 30, 999999, tzinfo=tzfile('/usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC'))
In [95]: t.tzname()  
#It return None
```

However,

```
In [96]: t = datetime.time(6, 15, 30, 999999, dateutil.tz.tzutc())                                                            
In [97]: t.tzname()                                                                                                           
Out[97]: 'UTC'
```

Tried alternatively

```
In [99]: t = datetime.time(6, 15, 30, 999999, dateutil.tz.gettz("America/New_York"))                                          
In [100]: t                                                                                                                   
Out[100]: datetime.time(6, 15, 30, 999999, tzinfo=tzfile('/usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York'))
In [101]: t.tzname()                                                                                                          
In [102]:    #return None

In [134]: !ls /usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC                                                                                         
/usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Do you have */usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC* on your system? (`ls /usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC`). Also, what's your *OS*, and *Python* version?

Comment: python 3.7 on linux @CristiFati

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [[Python 3.Docs]: datetime - time.**tzname**()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.time.tzname):

> If [tzinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.time.tzinfo) is `None`, returns `None`, else returns `self.tzinfo.tzname(None)`, or raises an exception if the latter doesn’t return `None` or a string object.

Looking at the problem in more detail:

> ```py
> >>> import datetime
> >>> import dateutil.tz
> >>>
> >>> tz0 = dateutil.tz.tzutc()
> >>> tz1 = dateutil.tz.gettz("UTC")
> >>> tz2 = dateutil.tz.gettz("America/New_York")
> >>>
> >>> tz0, tz1, tz2
> (tzutc(), tzfile('/usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC'), tzfile('/usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York'))
> >>>
> >>> type(tz0), type(tz1), type(tz2)  # Notice the differences
> (<class 'dateutil.tz.tz.tzutc'>, <class 'dateutil.tz.tz.tzfile'>, <class 'dateutil.tz.tz.tzfile'>)
> >>> isinstance(tz0, datetime.tzinfo), isinstance(tz1, datetime.tzinfo), isinstance(tz2, datetime.tzinfo)
> (True, True, True)
> >>>
> >>> tz0.tzname(None), tz1.tzname(None), tz2.tzname(None)
> ('UTC', None, None)
> ```

So, apparently for *tzfile* objects, *tzname* doesn't return the timezone string, and that is for a good reason since such a file contains all the timezone history (with parts that could have changed over time), also its alternates, and more info that may vary with the date.

As an alternative, you could extend `datetime.time` and override its *tzname* method, but I see this as a workaround.

*code.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import datetime
import dateutil.tz


class time_tzfile(datetime.time):
    def tzname(self):
        if isinstance(self.tzinfo, dateutil.tz.tzfile):
            return getattr(getattr(self.tzinfo, "_ttinfo_std", None), "abbr", None)
        return super().tzname()


def main():
    t = time_tzfile(6, 15, 30, 999999, dateutil.tz.tzutc())
    print("{:}\n  Type: {:}\n  Name: {:s}".format(t.tzinfo, type(t.tzinfo), t.tzname()))
    t = time_tzfile(6, 15, 30, 999999, dateutil.tz.gettz("UTC"))
    print("{:}\n  Type: {:}\n  Name: {:s}".format(t.tzinfo, type(t.tzinfo), t.tzname()))
    t = time_tzfile(6, 15, 30, 999999, dateutil.tz.gettz("America/New_York"))
    print("{:}\n  Type: {:}\n  Name: {:s}".format(t.tzinfo, type(t.tzinfo), t.tzname()))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} on {:s}\n".format(sys.version, sys.platform))
    main()
    print("\nDone.")
```

**Output**:

> ```bash
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q056055568]> python3 code.py
> Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 12 2018, 13:43:14)
> [GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
>
> tzutc()
>   Type: <class 'dateutil.tz.tz.tzutc'>
>   Name: UTC
> tzfile('/usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC')
>   Type: <class 'dateutil.tz.tz.tzfile'>
>   Name: UTC
> tzfile('/usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York')
>   Type: <class 'dateutil.tz.tz.tzfile'>
>   Name: EST
>
> Done.
> ```